# Quickblox connection is not successfully established every time in Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, webrtc, microsoft-edge, quickblox, ortc

I'm using 2.12.2 version of Quickblox, and Edge 42+ version. The call is made from iPhone8+ to the browser, and video chat isn't successfully established every time.

The console is displaying an error: 
ORTC18614: ORTC RTCIceGatherer: Transport endpoint allocation failed. hr=c004e00e.

And next:
SCRIPT5022: InvalidStateError     quickblox.min.js (1,363529).

Quickblox [documents](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk) state that Edge 14+ is supported, but there seems to be an issue.

Is anyone having a similar problem with Quickblox and Edge? It seems that Edge is not fully supported. Is there any solution to this problem?

EDIT: The same behavior is reproducible with the QuickBlox sample code. Also, after 30 seconds, the call is disconnected.

Comment: I try to visit Quickblox and find that they are offering various SDK. I want to confirm with you that which SDK you are using currently? If possible than try to provide any working example with detailed steps to produce the issue on our end. We will try to make a test with it and try to check the issue. thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for the quick answer. 
I am using the JavaScript SDK. I have also tried ( on MS Edge) to run the provided sample for Web from here: https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web  and it turns out that I got the same behavior: not every connection is successful on MS Edge, and when the session is established, it breaks after 30 seconds. Everything works fine with Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for providing the sample link. I will try to make a test and try to inform you my testing result. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I made a test and I used Safari on iPhone and MS Edge on my PC. The connection stays for about 2 mins. Can you please inform us, Which browser you are using on your phone? It can help to narrow down the issue.